# What's the regex for date range format like January 1 - 31, 2018?

Tags: c#, regex, date-range

I am reading date range/ period value using C#. The usual format is mm/DD/YYYY - mm/DD/YYYY.

But the period is some times formatted like January 1-31,2018 or February 1-28,2018.

What's the regular expression to identify these occurrences ?

Comment: Are you looking for a regular expression or for the custom date format?

Comment: that's right regex for the mentioned  date format

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this regular expression: [^\d/-], this will skip well formatted dates and filters out the other records from input set.